# Constrain force tree to an irregular boundary d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am placing circles (nodes) onto a choropleth map. I derive the centroid for each state feature and use this as the circle x and y coordinates. The state features are loaded in via a json file. Then I call a d3 force simulation to cluster them nicely around the centre of each state. This works nicely for most states until you get to places like Florida or California which are long and thin, and the nodes appear outside the state boundary. Is it possible to constrain the force simulation inside the irregular shape of the state boundary? Possibly using d3.polygon to test that the dot was still inside the store. but I can't quite work out how. My code currently looks like this:

```
parent.selectAll('circle')
        .data(d => d.votes)
        .enter()
        .call(sim)
        .append('circle')
        .attr('id', d => d.id + d.name)
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y)
        .attr('r', circleSize)

    } // eslint-disable-line

    function sim(dots) {
            const data = dots.data()
            const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
                .force("x", d3.forceX(function (d) { return d.x }))
                .force("y", d3.forceY(function (d) { return d.y }))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(d => (circleSize * 1.3)))
            for (var i = 0; i < 600; ++i) simulation.tick()
        }
```

Florida appears like this:

[image]